# Sharepoint 2016- How to add a calendar from sharepoint 2013 on to the new page in sharepoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin, 2016

We have a team calendar on the previous SharePoint 2013 which is still currently in use.

However I am now creating a new SharePoint site in a modern 2016(?) and I can't find a way to paste it into the new site.

I tried to export events from SharePoint calendar into the outlook calendar but that didn't work- however if you know how to do that, it would be a good solution.

Otherwise is there a way to paste the calendar into the new SharePoint page?

Sorry my SharePoint skill set is poor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible to sync( or display) SharePoint 2013 calendar with SharePoint 2016 site page without coding.

But you can copy all events from your existing SharePoint 2013 calendar to SharePoint 2016 calendar. 
To achieve it follow next steps:

1. Open "All Events" view of your SharePoint 2013 Calendar
2. Click on Quick Edit icon
3. Copy all events
4. Open "All Events" view of your SharePoint 2016 Calendar
5. Enter Quick Edit mode
6. Paste all events
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: Thank you @Raf I will try out your method. If I was to do coding, what steps would I need to take?Im ready for a challenge!

Comment: @mysteriousindividual for example, you can create workflow on your original SP2013 Calendar within SharePoint Designer. In workflow you can call POST request to SP 2016 REST API to create events.

Comment: Per my test, copy all events from your existing SharePoint 2013 calendar to SharePoint 2016 calendar using quick edit works.